# What is the best way to communiate between C++ and Python on Hardware?

Tags: python, c++, ipc

Setup: Robot that runs on C++ and an RL training-algo in python. Robot loop runs at 1kHz (can go higher).

Goal: To send the robot-state information to the RL training online and send the control inputs back to the robot.

Is there a best-way to achieve communication to and fro between C++ and Python processes (without having to use [Robot-Operating-System](https://www.ros.org/))?

Thank you

Comment: Who is ros and why can't he be involved? There are many ways to communicate. If one program runs the other, pumping things through stdin/stdout may be enough (remember to flush buffers). Zeromq is a great toolkit. A mini web server in one of them with a REST interface is great.

Comment: What is "ros"? Is one process launched by the other, or do they get launched independently? Are they running on the same machine?

Comment: 1kHz is nothing on modern hardware... I'm trying to think of an IPC mechanism that _couldn't_ handle 1kHz. I echo the suggestion to look into zeromq; it has a straightforward API, has implementations for dozens of programming environments, and is supposed to be very fast.

Comment: **Inter Process Communication** is probably the term you're looking for

Comment: I'm referring to https://www.ros.org/.

Both the processes are running independently. They are on the same machine.

Thank you. Will look into Zeromq.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would do the same as @tdelaney and @cdhowie already mentioned: using IPC socket communication. However, I think it would be overkill to use zeromq or external library to do so, since using only Python standard libraries should be fine and equally easy. Depending of your application, using shared memory could be way more efficient, but it is harder to setup and have limitations (the two processes must run of the same machine, among others). There is already many posts about this topic. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34315470/ipc-between-c-application-and-python) is very close to what you are trying to achieve and the answers are very detailed.

Comment: Yet I can't comment. And to me it somehow answers to the question, since the post I'm pointing to has all the information.

Comment: zeromq is one of many options of course, but I don't see how its overkill. Its easy to link or import the C++ and python components and it does most of the IPC heavy lifting for you. A few lines of zmq code replaces hundreds of lines of socket code. If the data is one way traffic of ascii text with line feeds, then yeah, a simple pipe will do. If its significantly complicated and needs a message passing interface, that's more in line with zeromq.

Comment: Yes that's true that it depends on the application, and I'm using it for advanced applications so I know it is very convenient. Here I made the assumption that since the author mentioned [ROS](https://www.ros.org/) (Robot Operating System)  and 1khz communication, I guess it is intended to be part of an interface between a robot (real or simulated) and a controller, probably running of the same hardware. So usually the data are just 1D or 2D arrays of floats, nothing fancy. But of course I may be wrong.

Comment: Thank you @milembar. Sorry, I should have been more clearer in the question. My situation is exactly as you described. I have a robot that runs on C++ and an RL training in python, and I want to update data with the actual robot states.

Comment: Yeh, ROS was a big hint though. Personally  I'm doing the same as you, and people I'm working with implemented some shared memory for me. It is extremely efficient, but it is quite tricky to implement properly. If you are advanced in C++, and if you want something that last in time very reliably, I would suggest to do the same, but it could take a week to implement depending on your skill and existing C++ codebase (Python side shouldn't be the most difficult part actually).